# How to create new core in solrj

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, solrj

I am trying to create new core using solrj. I need it to prepare test for my app. I think this code is incomplete or wrong because every time I got a error "no core candidates".

```
package com.itsystems.talentapp.config;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.CoreAdminRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.CoreAdminResponse;
import org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class SolrConfig {

    @Autowired
    SolrClient solrClient;


    @Bean
    @Profile("test")

    public EmbeddedSolrServer embeddedSolrServer() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        String folder = "src/main/resources/solr/";
        String coreName = "candidates";

        CoreAdminResponse e = new CoreAdminRequest().createCore(coreName, folder, solrClient);
        CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(folder);
        container.load();
        return new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "candidates");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No such core: candidates
```

Version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does this directory `src/main/resources/solr/` contain the core called candidate?

Comment: No containd because first I want to create new core :-)

Comment: In the above code, you are loading a core, not creating one. A core requires configuration to be present, which isn't in your case. If you want to create cores at runtime, use `CoreAdminRequest` to create the core first before loading it.

Comment: Or you can write your own custom code, that creates your core directory, copies `conf` directory from basic_configsets to your core directory and creates a `core.properties` file with core name in it. Then run above code to load it.

Comment: What have you tried? According to the apidoc, [there's a `create` method](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/core/CoreContainer.html) described as "Creates a new core, publishing the core state to the cluster"

Comment: What should be in " Map<String,String> parameters"? How to prepare this?

Comment: Here's a link to [link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.CoreAdminRequest). However, do note that the CoreAdminRequest is experimental and might change. An easy way out is what I mentioned in my second comment, just have a standard sample core directory somewhere on your SOLR server with config directory. And copy it to `src/main/resources/solr/` from your code, and write a file called `core.properties` containing one line `name=yourcorename`. Then load it using the same code as you've mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for help but still problem is unsolved. Maybe it's wrong because I want to use EmbeddedSolrServer?

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedSolrServer': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: I missed few folders and config file. Thank you @Gautam for help. Proper code:
 Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        String folder = "src/main/resources/solr/";
        String coreName = "candidates";
        CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(folder);
        container.load();
        return new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, coreName);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed few files and cfg.
Correct code:

```
 @Bean
public SolrClient solrClient() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    String folder = "src/main/resources/solr/";
    String coreName = "candidates";
    CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(folder);
    container.load();
    return new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, coreName);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what those files are. I want to create a new core with java client in the Solr server which is not my local machine.