# Getting org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection

Tags: solr, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Apache Solr 8.2 in a Ubuntu 18.4 LTS machine. I was able to create multiple cores which are all having data driven schema configuration. I have opened 8983 port. I was able to access to URL from my local server and was able to index data into my Solr core.

Now I have a job running on a Tomcat server that runs on the same machine as the Solr server. When I try to connect to the Solr server and try to index data, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection
```

I do not understand why this error occurs as the connection attempt is made from within the same machine. Also I do not have any issue when I try to connect to the core from my local server.

Comment: This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808251/solrj-server-refused-connection.  If it does, please be sure to "upvote" it.

Comment: What URL are you using the connect to your Solr server? That error indicates that your client isn't able to connect at all - you can also test this by using `wget` or `curl` on your server against the URL you've configured to see what the response is.

Comment: @MatsLindh, I am using the same URL using which I am able to generate my index from my local machine. I dont think the issue is with the URL.

Comment: The error message is that the client can't connect to the server. The URL is what tells the client where to connect - and how to connect - it's the first place I'd start testing, and do it from the same user as runs your application server. There can internal firewalling on the server itself between processes. Do the error occur in the Solr log or in your custom code?